Derivation of formula for (C,1) summability of integrals
I'm having trouble understanding why the (C,1) formula for integrals is given by $$ \lim_{\lambda\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\lambda}\bigg(1- \frac{x}{\lambda} \bigg)f(x) \,dx  $$
I understand that we want something analogous to what happens for series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$. That is, the $(C,1)$ limit is given by $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_1+ \cdots+ s_n}{n} $$ where $s_k= \sum_{m=0}^{k}a_m$
For integrals this would yield $$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda} \int_{0}^{\lambda} \int_{0}^{x}f(t) \,dt \,dx$$
However, I do not see how this equals the integral above. I searched on Titchmarsh book on Fourier integrals but he merely states the equality with no explanation.

If we write out $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n s_k$ explicitly in terms of the $a_k$s we see that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n s_k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n (n-k+1)a_k = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(1-\frac{r}{n})a_{r+1}.
$$
Thus it would appear that the "natural" integral analogue should be $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \int_0^{\lambda} (1-\frac{x}{\lambda})f(x)$.
This is also compatible with the OP's suggestion: for a function defined on $[0,\infty)$ rather than $\mathbb N$, the natural replacement for the partial sum $s_k$ is the integral $s(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t$, and then the process of averaging the first $n$ partial sums corresponds to taking $\frac{1}{\Lambda}\int_{0}^{\Lambda}s(x)\mathrm{d}x$. This yields the formula
$$
\lambda^{-1}\int_{0}^{\lambda}\int_{0}^x f(t)dtdx.
$$
But now if we interchange the order of integration we obtain
$$
\lambda^{-1}\int_0^x f(t)\int_x^{\lambda} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^x \lambda^{-1}(\lambda-x)f(t)dt = \int_{0}^{x} (1-\frac{x}{\lambda})f(t)dt
$$

I will read you with more attention, but you are right I somehow put an extra 1/\lambda but I already corrected it

I'll edit my answer to remove the reference to the extra $\lambda^{-1}$ factor. (Otherwise I think it may just be confusing to read!)
